# Best way to delete duplicate rows in an intersection table based on foreign key column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking for a way to delete dupicate rows from an intersection table based on a foreign key from one of the tables from the opposite ends of the intersection table. For the sake of clarity, I'll say based on a foreign key value from the intersection table on the left 'tableA'.

```
    CREATE TABLE tableA
    (
        link varchar(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(64) NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE tableB
    (
        link varchar(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        name varchar(64) NOT NULL
    )

    CREATE TABLE tableA_AND_tableB--Intersection Table
    (
        link varchar(64) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
        LtableA varchar(64) references tableA(link),
        LtableB varchar(64) references tableB(link)
    )
```

Basically, I want to delete all duplicate rows in the intersection table based on the 'LtableA' foreign key field. For instance: Say I have 20 duplicates of 'LtableA = id20140722' in 'tableA_AND_tableB', how do I go about deleting all the rows matching the value 'id20140722' in 'tableA_AND_tableB' without affecting anything else?

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Step 1 - determine how to tell the difference between a duplicate and the row you want to keep.

Comment: So if an id is in both tableA and tableB you want to delete both rows from both tables and leave nothing behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Delete from tableA_AND_tableB where LtableA = 'id20140722'
```

This will remove all rows from that table sepcifically with that ID. Alternatively you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows) for something that will delete all duplicates. Though that answer will keep either the first or last duplicate.

Comment: Not that great an answer, but upvoted to get his rep over 50 so he can post comments, which this should have been.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete duplicates but still keep one distinct copy of each row:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LtableA, LtableB ORDER BY link) row_num
  FROM tableA_AND_tableB
)
DELETE
FROM t
WHERE row_num > 1
  AND LtableA = 'id20140722'
```